# what's the relation between sin2x and tan x

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

I have noted a recurring example that reduces to the following form : $ \int \frac{ f(tan x ) }{ sin 2x } dx $

I think a u-substitution of a sort will be done but I'm not sure what.

Comment: Do you mean $\sin(2x)$ or $\sin^2(x)$?

Comment: please write down the whole problem

Comment: A t-substitution should do.

Answer (score 2):

use that $$\sin(2x)=\frac{2\tan(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}$$

Comment: im sorry is there a proof for that

Comment: Multiply numerator and denominator by $\cos^2 x$ and simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute $u=\tan(x)$, $du=dx\sec^2(x)$ to get
$$\int \frac{f(u)}{\sin(2x)}\frac{1}{\sec^2(x)}du=\int \frac{f(u)}{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}\cos^2(x)du$$
$$\int f(u)\frac{\cos(x)}{2\sin(x)}du = \int \frac{f(u)}{2u}du$$